# Should an asker feel pressure to accept an answer when it's not...?

Tags: discussion

I have a few questions out there that have answers but not really the "right" answer - like [SSRS email subscription with custom file name on the attachment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18517/ssrs-email-subscription-with-custom-file-name-on-the-attachment), which provided a work-around, and [can I add a custom SSRS e-mail subscription that forces the "TO" address](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18898/can-i-add-a-custom-ssrs-e-mail-subscription-that-forces-the-to-address), which provided very little input.

I'd still like to get more definitive answers to these questions, even if I must wait it out, and would prefer not to post a bounty at this time.  Should I feel pressure to wrap these questions up by accepting an answer?  Or is it acceptable to leave them out there unanswered?  Or should I offer a bounty?

The fact that our accept rate is out there for all to see makes me wonder if I should feel pressure - am I a bad participant otherwise?

Comment: I'll leave some time for someone else to address this too, but I don't think you should feel pressure to accept an incorrect or incomplete answer.  However, if an answer got you most of the way to the solution, it's probably worth accepting it.  Often the answers being incomplete are an issue with the question itself being incomplete.

Comment: Probably a brief comment about why that particular answer is wrong, and pressure is gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never get pressured into accepting a non-Answer to your Question. You should only ever check the mark if it helped.

If you're not getting the love you need on a Q, then reword the Q, offer a bounty, or ask for some guidance in our [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap), if that helps.

Comment: Answer accepted - pressure-free!